# LARAVEL 7, Undefined variable, cant pass Variable from Controller to View

Tags: php, laravel

im new at Laravel, and im making a CRUD following this tutorial:

https://appdividend.com/2020/03/13/laravel-7-crud-example-laravel-7-tutorial-step-by-step/

first i made it on my own, and then i just copied the code from GitHub, in both cases im getting in the variable inside the @foreach:

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: coronacases

I searched a bit and tryed some other solutions with no luck, so i started a new project with just index function to see if data is passed from controler to view.

This is my code,
Controller:

```
// TestController


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $name = 'hugo';

        return view('test', compact('name'));
    }
```

Alternative sintaxys tested in Controller:

```
/***
* return view('/test', compact('name'));
* return view('name', ['name' => 'James']); with out $name = 'hugo'; earier.
* return view('test', $name]);
* return view('test')->with('name', $data);
* return view('test')->with('name', 'hugo'); with out $name = 'hugo'; earier.
* other solutions tryed here dosnt seems to change anything.
***/
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('test');
});
Route::resource('test', 'TestController');
```

Alternative Routes Tested:

```
/***
* Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');
*
* Route::get('/', function () {
*    return view('test', ['name' => 'James']);
*}); //this one worked, but its not getting data from Controller, so its now what i need
*
*Route::get('/', function () {
*    return view('test', ['name' => $data]);
*}); //didnt work
*
***/ // I think that the problem is here, im having trouble understanding Routes at Laravel Docs
```

View:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also tryed at View:

```
/***
* $data
* <?php echo $data ?>
* {{ $name ?? '' }}
***/
```

All this Test, and im getting same error, Im missing Something and i cant figure it out... or i have some trouble with Laravel,the sure things is that im stuck.

Complementary info:

[php artisan route:list resoult:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz92k.png)

Environment information

Laravel version:
7.16.1,
Laravel locale:
en,
Laravel config cached:
false,
PHP version:
7.4.6.

Request

URL
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Method
GET

Headers

host
127.0.0.1:8000
user-agent
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0

I also tryed with php artisan view:cache && php artisan view:clear

Comment: if you go to the root of that site `/` you will get an undefined variable error because there is no data being sent to the view (no `name` variable) ... if you go to `/test` you should not get that error because `name` is being passed to the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined a function called `index` on your `TestController` but you have not used it.
In your route, you are not using the controller and that function ,  so you get this error.
Your method is like : **route** > **view** 
It should be : **route** > **controller** > **view**

So Change your route  :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('test');
});
```

to

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks both for solutions, worked on test, Get in back to tutorial, i added `Route::get('/index', 'CoronasController@index');` to make the redirect work.
thanx again for so fast response